# Init part of a bigger Matrix by using a smaller matrix in C++ Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have checked https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html, but it's not helpful.
what I need is a function which have two input and one output like this:

```cpp
Input1: Matrix<type,4,4>//which is a blank matrix, needed to fill
//0 0 0 0
//0 0 0 0
//0 0 0 0
//0 0 0 0

Input2: Matrix<type,3,3>//which have filled in other place.
//1 4 7 
//2 5 8 
//3 6 9 

Output: Matrix<type,4,4>
//1 4 7 0
//2 5 8 0
//3 6 9 0
//0 0 0 0
```

I have tried `conservativeResize` with a `MatrixXf` Matrix

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXf result(3, 3);
result = mat3x3;
result.conservativeResize(4, 4);
return result;
```

but this function need to be called very frequent, I wouldn't like to use realloc, I'd like to init the bigger mat by using the smaller one to save CPU time.

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make this way more complicated than it needs to be.

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXf result = Eigen::MatrixXf::Zero(4, 4);
result.topLeftCorner(3, 3) = mat3x3;
```

If you know that it's always 4x4 and 3x3, consider using fixed-size matrices for better performance.

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix3f mat3x3;
Eigen::Matrix4f result = Eigen::Matrix4f::Zero();
result.topLeftCorner<3, 3>() = mat3x3;
```

If, on the other hand, the matrix is huge and you want to avoid initializing most of it to zero first before overwriting it immediately, use something like this:

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXf result(rows, cols);
result.topLeftCorner(input.rows(), input.cols()) = input;
result.bottomLeftCorner(rows - input.rows(), input.cols()).setZero();
result.rightCols(cols - input.cols()).setZero();
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of writing this would be:

```
Matrix<type,4,4> output = input1;
output.topLeftCorner<3,3>() = input2;
```

An alternative would be:

```
Matrix<type,4,4> output;
output << input2 << input1.topRightCorner<3,1>() 
       << input1.bottomRows<1>();
```

If you don't need to keep `input1`, you can avoid copying into a new `output` matrix, of course. And if `input1` is always a zero matrix, you can use the corresponding `Zero()` matrices instead.